# Parse iOS Unit Testing a subclass of PFUser

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, parse-platform, pfobject

I'm trying to unit test (with XCTest) a subclass of a subclass of PFObject but am getting the warnings for all such subclasses that are part of the testing target:

```
Class MySubclassOfSubclassOfPFObject is implemented in both /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/84C7811F-348E-42EF-9FF4-F243DB669591/MyApp.app/MyApp and /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A84479A8-1ACD-4F7B-B02D-A28CB412CD14/tmp/MyAppTests.xctest/MyAppTests. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

I'm also getting an exception for my subclass of PFUser:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to register both ParseUser and ParseUser as the native PFObject subclass of _User. Cannot determine the right class to use because neither inherits from the other.'
```

I've installed Parse 1.12 via cocoapods and running XCode 7.2.

My podfile looks like this:

```
target 'Watchi' do
use_frameworks!
pod 'Parse'
end

target 'WatchiTests' do

end
```

In my Test Target Build Settings, I've added $(SRCROOT) to User Header Search Paths (recursive), otherwise the Test Target can't find PFObject+Subclassing.h.

Any idea as to why this might be happening?  For some reason the unit tests/parse think there are two versions of these classes, but there's only one file of each in my code.